# App Store Connect - In-App Purchase - Waiting for loading

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

All my IAP's have the status "Waiting for loading", why i don't have "Ready for submit" status or a submit button in my IAP's.

All informations are set.

Anyone have a solution ?

[image]

Comment: You should ask only in english. You could read this [why you should ask in english only](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i changed the language ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem !

You have to disable "Activate Hosted Content" in the IAP and save the change.
[image]

The status change to "Ready to Submit" and the section "In-App Purchase" in your build are unlocked, so you can add your IAP's to your build and next submit your app.